# SVG: get arc segment length

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm looking into ways to calculate `path.getTotalLength()` in Node.js and it seems that a polyfill is not available. So far I managed to compute all other pathCommands except `A`.

For instance, knowing last X and Y from `M` segment, and also having all the `A` segment values, how to determine the length of this path?

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M8 15 A7 7 0 1 0 8 1">
</svg>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MDN has some great documentation in regards to the various path commands.

> *[MDN > SVG Tutorial > Paths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths)*

Here is how you decompose the provided path commands:

`M 8 15` = Move To (Absolute)

```
x = 8
y = 15
```

`A 7 7 0 1 0 8 1` = Arc (Absolute)

```
rx = 7
ry = 7
x-axis-rotation = 0
large-arc-flag = 1
sweep-flag = 0
x = 8
y = 1
```

I followed this [Mathematics Exchange post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/830630/101116) to compute the arc length, given the states path commands. Since the x and y radii of your arc are equal, this is a bit easier.

**Note:** I am not sure what you would need to do if they are different.

```js
const x1 = 8, y1 = 15;
const x2 = 8, y2 =  1;
const r  = 7; // Since rx === ry, this is a bit easier

const d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2));
const theta = Math.acos(1 - (Math.pow(d, 2) / (2 * Math.pow(r, 2))));

const arcLength = theta * r;

console.log(arcLength); // Arc Length = 21.9911
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="
      M 8 15
      A 7 7 0 1 0 8 1
    " fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />

  <!-- Move to and begin arc at (8, 15) -->
  <circle cx="8" cy="15" r="1" stroke="none" fill="red" />
  
  <!-- End arc at (8, 1) -->
  <circle cx="8" cy="1" r="1" stroke="none" fill="cyan" />
  
  <!-- Radius of (7, 7) -->
  <circle cx="15" cy="7.5" r="1" stroke="none" fill="lime" />
  
  <!-- Center -->
  <circle cx="8" cy="7.5" r="1" stroke="none" fill="gold" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Why do you say "// Since rx === ry, this is a bit easier"?

Comment: What is basically needed is a way to know the length of any arc in the 0-359.999 degree range.

Comment: Because there is a mathematical formula for the perimeter of a circle but there isn't one for the perimeter of an ellipse.

Comment: Although there are many approximations - some better than others: https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/ellipse-perimeter.html

Comment: Is distance from (rx,ry) -> (x,y) the actual radius? How would you calculate that, with distance square root? Or if this distance is different from (x1,y1) -> (rx,ry), how can we determine the length of the arc? Thanks

Comment: Anyways guys, I understand there are some limitations in respect to ellipses, where approximations are used/needed. I have some working code that converts the Arc segments to cubic bezier and return the proper value with a `0.001` to `0.002` delta from `getTotalLength`. The conversion also allows me to create a `getPointAtLength` feature. We probably shouldn't spend more time with this issue, it's a SVG 1.1 limitation in my books. But thanks again guys. Cheers